# Although-Yet or comma

Tags: conjunctions, correlating-conjunctions

> Although he achieved/ great success/  he couldn't win fame.

This is an error detection question   from last year exam. And answer is *No Error.*
But neither *comma(,)* nor *yet* is used after success. eg:

> Although he is poor **yet** (or *comma*) he is honest.

because **although** is paired with **yet** or **comma** [(see)](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/124463/346804)

So why no error.

Because **yet** or **comma** should be used as-

- Although he achieved great success ***yet*** he couldn't win fame.

or

- Although he achieved great success ***,***  he couldn't win fame.

Comment: Why do you think the comma is *required*?  Is this something you have been taught?  Also why do you think *yet* is grammatically correct?  The sentence already contains one conjunctive adverb (*although*) -- why do you think it needs another?  Please add more detail to the question, so we can write a better answer.

Comment: @Andrew sorry but i have studied that Although take either 'yet' or 'comma' after main clause. Ex: Although he is poor yet he is honest.

Comment: Yes, I thought so.  This is incorrect.  Pick one or the other, but not both.  I'm not sure what *poverty* has to do with *honesty* ... but in any case either, **"Although he is poor, he is honest,"** or, **"He is poor, yet he is honest,"** is perfectly fine.

Comment: Note in your updated link, the top answers say the "Although ... yet" structure is wrong, or at best *archaic*.

Comment: Slightly ironically, the correct way to use `yet` would be to put a comma in front (not after):  
`Although he is poor, yet he is honest.`  but as noted, this reads as old-fashioned, or rather formal.